Medical Education - Excluding Audiobooks & Text-To-Speech Software, What Auditory Resources can Students be Directed to use?
Aside from audiobooks, I seldom come across medical education resources for students who either:
A. Want to learn by audio
B. Need to learn by audio
A.
There are many students who casually want to pursue this medium for learning. For them, any and all resources are valuable.
B.
However, for the students who need these resources, there is often a reason that they are simultaneously trying to address or adapt to. In this case, it is even more difficult to find an audio resource that would not only provide medical education, but also provide them with another tool to work with.
Far From a Perfect Example:
Some students who rely on these resources can benefit greatly from adding focus to vocabulary. To do so, studying etymology is a great resource. So, while it might be feasible to find an audiobook for a medical etymology publication, it would not be a practical result. The effect would essentially be like listening to a dictionary.
EX:
I absolutely loved the answer to this question:
Q - By Zwerg: Where do I get deeper information about the origin of anatomical names?
A - By Diana Petitti
Where do I get deeper information about the origin of anatomical names?
Limitations:
I understand that the question of audio resources alone can be tricky. It is a shot in the dark to ask about an audio resource that is both educational on the subject matter and may also be of good service to the students who rely on the medium in the first place. It is a very difficult domain due to the sheer volume of recorded lectures which are largely unusable for this purpose because the audio alone with lack the images and unspoken text on the slides.
What Can be Done?
Unless I misunderstand something, these two categories seem like a fairly niche market to cater to within medical education, one much more so than the other. Maybe this will continue to change over time, but for now I am not sure how much of the problem is due to me missing something, or due to there being a lack of resources to find in the first place.

You're excluding audio books and text-to-speech, so I'm at a bit of a loss what you're looking for. I assume you also exclude videos since those usually rely heavily on the visual component. And who are the students here? Are you addressing high school, college, medical students, or doctors? And who the heck are Zwerg and Diana Petitti?

@CareyGregory - I'm looking for exactly that. An educational resource in audio format that isn't just a verbalization of a source not suited for that medium: textbook, dictionary, publication... I am trying to find something made for the audio medium, or one that at least converts more practically. Not easy, if I knew, then I wouldn't be asking for help. This is for higher ed, med students and everything above. I know it just makes this harder. Zwerg posted that question here & Diana Petitti answered it. I should have just put a link, my mistake.

If it's not a textbook, dictionary, or publication then I have no idea what you're looking for. Can you describe an example?

@CareyGregory If I understand OP correctly, it's not that they are looking for something outside of those categories, rather it's that they are looking for something specifically tailored to audio-only. What they are not looking for is things that were originally designed as written text and then converted to audio-only.

@JJ123 So you are basically looking for a podcast or similar?

@CareyGregory - Yes, that is very much the case. It is the difference between content turned into audio vs content made for audio. BryanKrause, maybe a podcast is the closes approximation, but the "similar" category is a rich unknown that I'd also like to learn more about. Either way, fitting this entire matter into a podcast seems very difficult.

The obvious answer is podcasts. There are a huge range of podcasts that do essentially exactly what you ask for and are made for various audiences. Some good ones off the top of my head - The Curbsiders which is an internal medicine podcast that discusses a whole range of topics usually presented by guests. It's geared towards practicing physicians and isn't meant to be comprehensive exactly but I think it's a good example of an audio-focused resource. There are also a number of board exam/USMLE focused podcasts. USMLE Step 2 Secrets is a podcast that works through the USMLE Step 2 Secrets review book, but it is not an audio book per-se. Divine Intervention is another popular resource/podcast that covers all 3 Step exams and more and is entirely focused on audio-only content.
The broader (and less satisfying) answer is that any lecture, podcast, or audio book would be do what you want, with the caveat that it must be optimized for listening. I don't think there is any one category or style of presentation that totally fits your needs, instead it depends on the amount of effort put into creating a useful tool that does not rely on video or physical/digital text. So basically, that means you have to search through these many mediums and find which specific resources fit the bill. Pathoma's accompanying lectures are a great example of a resource that, on the surface, does not meet your requirements (it is an accompaniment to a physical book and it is provided as a voiceover with slides). However, it is presented in such a way that one could listen, without watching the videos, and get 99% of the benefit.
Fundamentally, medical education at almost all levels is going to require some visual/text resources. Most exams are written, many concepts can be more clearly explained through the use of graphics, some things require images, diagrams, or charts, and the volume of information students need probably precludes the exclusive use of audio - you can only listen to so much in a given time. So any audio-only resource is likely to be hamstrung from the start. It's hard to work through practice problems in an audio-only format, you can't show charts, graphs, or images, and your limited by time. It's just a sub-optimal way to deliver the material and I doubt there is even a "best" way to do it. A company/individual that wants to create an audio only resource has to spend considerable time and energy optimizing for the format - more so than other formats and with less end payoff. That translates to fewer dedicated resources for audio-focused learners.
